Reintroduce Foreign Keys where data is mismatched
I need to change a PK to clustered. For this I need to drop the constraint and recreate this. But I can't drop until removing the FK's. I can drop the FK and change the PK. But, recreating the FK fails because of mismatch data.
What approach should I take?
I don't want to modify the data. I am looking for something like adding a foreign key with "NOT VALID" so that it doesn't check the constraint for existing data. But it doesn't seem that SQL server supports this.

How could they already exist, if the data mismatch? Did you set them as NOCHECK at some point? (read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-foreign-key-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver16)

That must have happened at some point before, I have a backup of a db and this was the state the data was in. It was only a handful of rows. I just come across the NOCHECK command this solves my problem when adding the foreign key

Just note that these FKs will be worthless

I've just seen that this will not enforce the check on future rows either, this is no good in that case. I thought it was a just a temporary nocheck on creation

If you can't create them because of data mismatch, than I doubt they where there before. Can you show us the create script for that table

The only way to setup a FK is to make sure first that all the data matches, you cannot make a FK that only works on new data and not on old, it's all or nothing

You're right it looks like it's been modified at some point so that the original FK is with nocheck. The original table creation didn't have this, it might have happened as part of a patch. That explains everything. Thank you

From reading a little further online, the with no check is only applied on creation of the key. So that old data is still valid. But it still ensures that new data keeps the referential integrity. The use would be when importing data or dealing with scenarios that need that bad data. Is this true? In that case WITH NO CHECK might be a valid option in some scenarios

Planning to have bad data just sounds like a bad idea, but I know sometimes you just have to make things work.
